# redirect subdomain to same subdomain name but different domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

i have site called exmaple.com have a lot of subdomains

```
test1 , test2 , test2.example.com
```

how could i redirect subdomains with exact subdomain but to another domain name for example

```
test1 , test2 , test3.example.net
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use %1 %2 etc. to grab regex-match groups from the RewriteCond.

As you probably know, $1 $2 matches regex groups from the RewriteRule

Off the top of my head, this is pretty straightforward with mod_rewrite active:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_HOST} (.+)\.example\.com
 RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.example.net$1 [R,QSA]
```

This assumes that you are serving all those subdomains from a single virtual host, but if you aren't, you can just copy this ruleset into each one's config or .htaccess individually.

Answer (score 1):

This may work. Put it in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.example.net/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Haven't tested it, but it should give you a start.