# Redirect all subdomains to new domain

Tags: iis, web-config

I want to redirect (301) all traffic to a new domain using a `web.config` rule, but the site is also handling a growing list of subdomains which will also need redirection.

How do I write a rule for the following?

- The old domain is foo.com
- The new domain is bar.org
- Everything before and after the domain (foo.com) needs to be redirected to the new domain:

```
a.foo.com -> a.bar.org
b.foo.com -> b.bar.org
c.foo.com/some-page -> c.bar.org/some-page
d.foo.com/some/other/page -> d.bar.org/some-page
```

Basically like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507548/redirect-subdomain-to-same-subdomain-name-but-different-domain-name) but for IIS.

This is my attempt so far:

```
    <rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^(.*)\.foo\.com$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}.bar.org/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Most of the samples there seem to require access to IIS which I don't have (can only use web.config file), and they also don't include examples of the situation I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @LexLi thanks though - in the end, that guide did help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I finally got it working:

```
    <rule name="redirect" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^(.*)\.foo\.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.bar.org/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I don't fully understand the rule though :/ It doesn't work without setting "negate" to false for example.